# Is it possible to change v-autocomplete width?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using Autocomplete Component in Vue Toolbar. But it's width is fixed (May be). Is it possible to change the with of `v-autocomplete`

```
<v-autocomplete
            v-model="select"
            :loading="loading"
            :items="items"
            :search-input.sync="search"
            chips
            clearable
            hide-details
            hide-selected
            append-icon=""
            solo
            item-text="name"
            item-value="symbol"
            label="Where do you want to live..."
            background-color="white"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
            class="widthOfSearch"
            style="width: 350px!important;"
            >
            <template v-slot:no-data>
                <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-title>
                    Search for your favorite
                    <strong>Room</strong>
                </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
            </template>
</v-autocomplete>

Link: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes
```

Comment: As far as I know all vuetify components are compatible with the grid system, so it should scale to whatever the width of the parent column is?

Comment: No parent column fixed. ```v-container```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
  <v-autocomplete
      ----------      
  </v-autocomplete>
</v-col>
```